# How to call REST API related to Azure Search through postman?

Tags: rest, azure, logic, postman

I am trying to call REST API related to Azure Search through postman.
Here is the API link: (Check Step 1: Create a data source)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

**Have sent parameter api-key: [admin key] in form-data and other through jSON object.**

[image]

I am getting 403 error.

Whats the correct way to get required output?

Update :

Changed position of api-key. Still getting the error as :

[image]

Is there any additional setting for postman to work with Azure's REST APIs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure that you pass `api-key` in `Headers` instead of `form-data` and also all the headers should be selected. Once you do that, things should work just fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi,I have provided api-key in header now. Still it's giving same error. Do we need to have some settings to call Azure's REST APIs from postman? If yes, please provide me the reference. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please update your questions with the latest screenshots of Postman? I'm especially interested in looking at "Headers" tab. Obviously, please mask your access key in the headers.

Comment: It looks OK to me. Please make sure `azuresearch` in your request URL is replaced with the correct search service name and the key is correct. They key should be `Admin` key and not the `Query` key.

Comment: Thanks,it's done. Can you please have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158655/how-to-call-rest-api-for-azure-file-storage-using-postman

Comment: , Hi, please have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209985/how-to-open-blobs-on-browser-through-service