# How to call REST API through postman to create index in Azure?

Tags: java, rest, azure, logic

I am creating an application where I need to call REST API related to create data source as mentioned here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Here is how I am making my request :

[image]

I am getting following error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid. Details: index : The property 'type' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.IndexDefinition'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.\r\n"
    }
}
```

What should I do so that 'type' can be set correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to create a data source or index? Your request body is for creating a data source. Also, please stop tagging me in other questions.

Comment: If your trying to "create data source" then your posting to the wrong URL. https://[service name].search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2016-09-01

Comment: @GauravMantri Ok, will not tag you anywhere else. Thanks, just got the solution for the error.

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury , thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting to the wrong URL try the following

```
https://[service name].search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2016-09-01
```